# using loc to remove nan which appears in 2 or more columns

Tags: pandas, nan

I have a basic df as below and i want to remove NaN values when they appear in both Name and Age columns and not just one. the below code i am using removes the 3rd row even though Age = 16 and is not a NaN. ideally i want to use loc method as i have other conditions

thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['tom', 10, 'male'], ['nick', 15, 'male'], [np.nan, 16, 'male']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'sex'])
df_new = df.loc[((df['Name'].notnull()) & (df['Age'].notnull()))]
```

Comment: Do you mean ```df.loc[(~(df['Name'].isna()) & ~(df['Age'].isna()))]```

Comment: it still remove the 3rd row. i only want it removed it both Name and Age column have NaN and not just one

Comment: The right boolean is filter is `df.loc[~(df['Name'].isna() & df['Age'].isna())]`

Comment: You should use `|`: `df_new = df.loc[df['Name'].notnull() | df['Age'].notnull()]`

Comment: Maybe a relict of earlier tries, but there's 3 pairs of extra parentheses.

Comment: @mozway this works, thanks but can you explain where i went wrong as i wanted both columns to include nan to be removed so i dont understand why using 'or' works. thanks

Comment: You should read about [De Morgan's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) dropping if both are NaN is equivalent to keeping if either is not NaN.

Comment: ahh thats way too complex for me. im only a beginner who started coding last week

Comment: I would still use `dropna(subset=['Name', 'Age'], how='all')`